# Azure Resource Health

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, availability

GET the health of a single resource:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SubID>/resourceGroups/<rgName>/providers/<ResourceProvider>/<ResourceType>/<ResourceName>/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses/current?api-version=2015-01-01
```

The above api request is giving wrong health status for consequent time intervals. We are querying the api at regular intervals to check the availability of some Azure VMs. But sometimes the value is coming as *available* for a stopped VM.

We are following the below blog to access the status: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/reduce-troubleshooting-time-with-azure-resource-health/

Comment: but its talking about health state? so its healthy while being stopped? also, it might be that it just fail to update (when the VM just went to a stoppped state)?

Comment: Yes, the availability status is coming wrongly at times and which causes false alerts at our end. I'm not sure whether it's failed to update. Will that be a case where the status is not updating properly?
Also, I would like to know `"reasonChronicity":"Persistent"` what this key mean and is there any dependency between Azure Status and this key

Comment: well, i suppose there is some lag after the update? I suspect you'd need to raise a support ticket for this, I dont think this is something people here can help you with as you are doing requests to the api. Doubt people here can alter the way api answers you.